# Combine two columns (Date-Time Classes, ignore NA)

Tags: r, datetime-format

I have a data.frame something like this:

```
D = data.frame(a = c(NA,"2015-09-10"), b = c("2016-09-30",NA))
```

Here I'm not sure, whether this actually perfectly represents my data, because there are two columns of dates (date-time format, POSIXlt).

```
           a          b
1       <NA> 2016-09-30
2 2015-09-10       <NA>
```

Each column has entries/NA's, there are no double entries. I want to combine these two. So far I tried every version of `paste()`  or `merge()` I am aware of (though my knowledge is restricted).

The question is very closely related to [Combine two columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963977/combine-two-columns-in-r), still I cannot make it work, because `rowMeans()` only works on numerics.

Comment: Essentially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038371/merge-multiple-date-columns-into-one/43038812

Comment: Relevant line from the duplicated thread: `do.call(pmin, c(dat, na.rm=TRUE) )`

Comment: Thank you so much, `do.call(pmin, c(dat[c("col1","col2","col3")], na.rm=TRUE) )` did the job for me, hence I had a bigger data.frame.